# Jest fails to call spy on async function, but function is called in browser console

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've written a jest test to cover an onBlur event being called. Im using react-testing-library and material-ui.

Here is the test code:

```
test('fires onBlur handler', async () => {
  const spy = jest.fn()
  const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(
    <FormEmailAsync placeholder={'Your Email'} onBlurred={data => spy(data)} />
  )
  const fld = getByPlaceholderText('Your Email')
  expect(fld)
  userEvent.type(fld, 'test@gmail.com')
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  fireEvent.blur(fld)
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test@gmail.com')  
})
```

And the code I am trying to assert on

```
  const [theState, asyncFunc] = useAsyncFn(async value => {
    const returnedSchema = await schema.validate(value)
    return returnedSchema
  }, [])

  const onBlurFunc = async (name, event) => {
    let returnFromAsync = await asyncFunc(event)
    console.log(returnFromAsync)
    onBlurred(returnFromAsync)
  }
```

I've attempted to setup a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-shape-fkcez) but unfortunately this is failing with an error about wrapping the tests in an `act` block. This does not occur in my local environment.

How do I get this test to complete successfully?

Comment: Have you tried to do `await wait(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))`?

Comment: You know I thought of this just before I went to bed yesterday, tried it, and it worked! Did you want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: `expect(fld)` is a no-op. You probably want `expect(fld).toBeDefined()`

Comment: Yes axaic, you are right. that was an error, looks like I was going to `expect` something but wound up expecting... nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `await` for the method to be called:

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
```

Comment: But if you set the number of times to be called less than 1 the test will pass anyway. Because at the time of assertion that is true.